# Ruby on Rails: How do detect if access by JSON?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a GET URL that calls a controller method getInfo. It can be called by mydomain.com/getInfo.json?params=BLAHBLAH or mydomain.com/getInfo?params=BLAHBLAH

In the controller, is there a way to detect how the user called it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Within your controller's specific method, you can respond to different formats - for example:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json { render :json => @user }
end
```

You can respond to various formats (xml, js, json, etc) - you can get more information about respond_to and how to use it in your controller here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/InstanceMethods/respond_to

Comment: To perfectly annoying about this-this example works, but it's not really what OP asked. This example sets up responses to various types of calls, it doesn't actually tell your application if this particular  call was a JSON API request vs "HTML request"

Answer (score 34):

Yes. Within the controller you can call the `request.format` method to determine the format requested by the user.

If you need more than just the format, you can look at `request.url` for the full URL.  More details about the `request` object can be found [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).

Comment: Tips: You can do `==` comparisons on the returned [`Mime::Type`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/Mime/Type.html), e.g. `request.format == 'json'`. There's also a handy `#html?` method, e.g. `before_action :do_something if: "request.format.html?"`

Answer (score 14):

A list of ways to check for json

```
request.format == 'json'
request.format == :json
request.format.json?
request.path.match('json')
request.url.match('json')
respond_to do |format|
  format.json { render json: [] }
end
```

You can also check if request was an ajax request

```
request.xhr?
```

Comment: thanks for this, was very usefull as i wanted to know is the request was json or javascript.

Answer (score 12):

Here is an actual somewhat contrived working example, that answers the question of *how to detect if the call is JSON / XML API call vs an "HTML" call*. (Accepted answer doesn't answer that question, just tells you how to respond to various formats)

```
# We can use this in a before_filter
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, if: :api_request?

# Or in the action
def show
  @user = if api_request?
            User.where(api_token: params[:token]).first
          else
            User.find(params[:id])
          end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html 
    format.json { render :json => @user }
  end
end

private
  def api_request?
    request.format.json? || request.format.xml?
  end
```

Using a `respond_to` sets different types of responses, but it doesn't tell your application how the call was made unless you add some extra code that does it (see below for a crude example, just to illustrate the point.)

I wouldn't recommend this, interrogating `request` is much safer, and 10x times more useful, as the approach below is only useful much later in the request lifecycle ( right before the response is sent back to the client). If you have any logic in your before filters this wouldn't work at all.

```
# Have no way of using it in a before_filter
# In your controller
def show
  # I want to know if the call was JSON API - right here 
  # This approach wouldn't help at all. 
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { @api_request = false}
    format.json { @api_request = true; render :json => @user }
  end
end

def api_request?
  @api_request
end
```

Answer (score 8):

As easy as do:

```
request.path_parameters[:format] == 'json'
```

Comment: While this is not the appropriate answer to this question ( use respond_to as suggested by @michaeldcruz ), this is a good way to add the current extension to links so that, for example, a rabl file that references other URLs can work in both json and xml.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to check if it was an Ajax request you can check for a `header[X-Requested-With]` using `request.xhr?`

Example code snippet

```
if request.xhr?
  # Do the ajax stuff
else
  # Do normal stuff
end
```

Comment: I was looking for this! This is a much better solution, but that header is non-standard I believe (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26245601/179311). It's used by prototype, jQuery, and some other libraries when you use their ajax helpers, and the header can be added if you roll your own ajax call.