# Where does the HTTP Request Header X-Requested-With come from

Tags: http-headers, xmlhttprequest

As we know we can use the `X-Requested-With` http request header to judge that if a http request comes from Ajax or not.

Many javascript framework will auto add `X-Requested-With` header in their ajax request，such as [jQuery Ajax](http://api.prototypejs.org/ajax/)，[Prototype Ajax](https://github.com/sstephenson/prototype/blob/master/src/prototype/ajax/request.js).And as the wiki of [List of HTTP header fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) says the `X-Requested-With` is a **non-standard request header**.

After google many times , I haven't found who first come up with the `X-Requested-With` request header.

So I want to know if anybody else know where the `X-Requested-With` comes from ? Thanks...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

References to Prototype supporting `X-Requested-With` can be found in [Should there be a standard X-Ajax-Engine request header?](http://www.dev411.com/blog/2006/06/30/should-there-be-a-xmlhttprequest-user-agent/) (posted on 6/30/2006).

Reference in the jQuery source code repository on Github to the May 16, 2006 version of [ajax.js](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/commit/6e4f0ce05e88fada8c1767cc2fe7c6a77f2d3602) where `X-Requested-With` is originally added.

Dojo didn't see to add this until [02/09/08](https://bugs.dojotoolkit.org/ticket/5801) and references the other libraries:

> jQuery, Prototype, YUI and - as it seems - Mootools send the header
>   "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" with their XHRs.

By [2008-10-21 v1.4](http://mochi.github.io/mochikit/doc/html/MochiKit/), MochiKit calls this a standard:

> MochiKit.Async now sets the "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" header,
>   a de facto standard (Prototype, jQuery, Mootools).