# In Rails, how do I override the format from the URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a report that's available in HTML or PDF formats.  Sometimes, I want to display an error message instead of the report.  The error message should be wrapped in my application's usual layout.

This works fine if the request was for the HTML report, but if the PDF report was requested, I get "There was no default layout for MyController in #<ActionView::PathSet..."

My controller method looks like this:

```
def report
  unless report_available?
    render html: '<div class="error">Not available.</div>'.html_safe,
           :status => 404, :layout => true
    return
  end
  ...
end
```

I've tried adding `:formats => :html` or `:formats => [:html]` to the call to render, but it has no effect.  I've also tried setting `params[:format] = 'html'` before calling render, but that didn't help either.

How do I render a snippet of HTML using the default layout when the request was for `report.pdf`?

The full error message looks like:

> There was no default layout for MyController in #<ActionView::PathSet:0x00007fd3b842c370 @paths=[#<ActionView::OptimizedFileSystemResolver:0x00007fd3d0776c20 @pattern=":prefix/:action{.:locale,}{.:formats,}{+:variants,}{.:handlers,}", @cache=#<ActionView::Resolver::Cache:0x7fd3d0776bf8 keys=1 queries=0>, @path="/var/www/apps/myapp/releases/1/app/views">]>

And the stack trace looks like:

```
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/layouts.rb:420:in `_default_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/layouts.rb:389:in `block in _layout_for_option'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:94:in `resolve_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:74:in `find_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:58:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:50:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:103:in `_render_template'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (5.1.6) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:52:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:141:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:24:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:36:in `render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/usr/local/rbenv/versions/2.4.3/lib/ruby/2.4.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
activesupport (5.1.6) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in render'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (5.1.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:29:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (5.1.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in `render'
app/controllers/my_controller.rb:809:in `report'
```

I believe the problem is that it's looking for a layout with `.pdf.erb` instead of `.html.erb`, but I don't know how to change that.

Comment: Maybe something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7577829/1577357

Comment: @ZulhilmiZainudin, I don't want to handle different formats differently.  I want to serve everyone the same HTML error page.

Comment: It might be simplest to redirect to the html version of the page if unavavailbe and pdf. You could have the exact same logic in report if you made the not found a unique action. Added as a comment, as it is more of a workaround than a direct answer, which would probably look a lot like what @ZulhilmiZainudin suggested, and you have already expressed reluctance about.

Comment: Please include full detail on the error you are receiving.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is redirect to 404 page with this as a flash notice.

If you don't have a 404 page, you'd need one anyway.

Comment: So you're saying it's impossible to override the format from the URL?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the request format of your action:

```
def report
  request.format = :html
  # ..
end
```

You can also use it in a `before_action` filter

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :set_default_response_format

  protected

  def set_default_response_format
    request.format = :html
  end
end
```

Comment: This has no effect when set in the method.  I didn't try a before_action because that would complicate the logic.

Comment: None of both? How is your request being formed? This works for my project when the requested url has the form of `some.example/resource.html` and `some.example/resource.json`, forcing all requests to answer on `.json`

Comment: My URL looks like `example.com/my/123/report` or `example.com/my/123/report.pdf`.  The extensionless version works fine; the `.pdf` one fails.

Comment: Perhaps you need to [register PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41321630/8304905) as a first step, and then you might try this same solution or `respond_to do |format| format.pdf { render html: 'your_string'.html_safe } end`

Comment: As I understand it, `respond_to` is just for doing different things based on which format was requested.  I want to do the same thing no matter what was requested in the URL.

Comment: Yes but your problem seems to happen only with `.pdf`. If you send a request with `.json` I'm sure that with this solution it will answer as `.html`, please confirm. Also, did registering PDF helped?

Comment: `report` and `report.html` work OK.  `report.json` and `report.pdf` give the same error.  Registering PDF did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: OK, I tried a `before_action` just for testing, and setting `request.format` in the before action worked.  I'm not sure why it works as a before action but not in the method.  I suppose I could move the test into a before action, but it seems strange that it doesn't work when set later.